# Why can't I access the value of a hidden input field from my ASP.NET code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms

From my page's code-behind I want to access the value of this hidden field. The value is set properly. I confirmed by checking its value.

```
<div class="hiddenValues">
    <input id="HiddenReportId" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

From my code behind, I'm using the following to access the above input

```
string id = Request.Form["HiddenReportId"];
```

When I run the application this line throws a null exception. Any suggestions ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` needs to be inside of the `form` tag (which it may be, can't tell from the code snippet).  Also, it needs to have a `name` attribute:

```
<div class="hiddenValues">
  <input id="HiddenReportId" name="HiddenReportId" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Its `id` attribute may be redundant and isn't necessary if you're not using it.  But form elements are identified by their `name` attributes in a POST.

(It feels a bit unintuitive from an ASP.NET perspective to the uninitiated, I know.  ASP.NET convention is to identify everything by an `ID`, but web browsers use `name` when crafting a POST.  And the web browser knows nothing of the server-side technology being used, it follows HTTP standards instead.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm finding web development in general to be "less than intuitive" in many aspects. Turns out it was just the missing 'name' attribute. The 'input' was inside the 'form' tag. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DenaliHardtail: It's funny, because web development is primarily what I've always done and I find application development to be unintuitive :)